# Heroku Deployment error:connection refused

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, sequelize.js, web-deployment

I have deployed my app on heroku..but the problem is ,it is giving this error

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

my config.js file-

```
module.exports={
    port:process.env.PORT || 8082,
    production: {
        use_env_variable: process.env.DATABASE_URL
      },
    authentication:{
        jwtSecret: process.env.JWT_SECRET|| 'secret'
    }
}
```

my database connection file-

```
const Sequelize=require('sequelize')
const config=require('../config/config')

let sequelize=null;
if(process.env.DATABASE_URL){
     sequelize=new Sequelize(config.production.use_env_variable,{dialect:'mysql'})

}
else{    
     sequelize=new Sequelize('bloggy','root','12345678',{dialect:'mysql',host:'localhost'})

}
module.exports=sequelize
```

I am not understanding why it is throwing that error.. it was working fine locally?
can anyone please help?

Comment: *Is* the database running on localhost in Heroku? That seems... unlikely.

Comment: no..the problem is I am not understanding what the actual problem is..the else part in database file is for running locally

Comment: Well *is* the environment variable set in the Heroku environment? To what? *By* what?

Comment: sorry.. i am not understanding what you are saying...

Comment: You expect the connection information to come from DATABASE_URL, no? So... *what is it*? It's working fine locally, where you're *not using that*.

Comment: so how to set that vairable.. I thought just like process.env.PORT returns the heroku port, it will also return the DATABASE_URL.. also I went through many examples, it was written the same..can you help me with that?please?

Comment: Heroku knows what port it wants your app to listen on. How is Heroku supposed to know where your database is? Have you configured an add-on? I'd recommend research - either you'll have to manually provide the connection string, or read the Heroku docs to learn about the services they can provide for you. But that's too broad for SO, so I'll leave you to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that in Heroku you have set the `DATABASE_URL` in environment variable b running Heroku `config:set DATABASE_URL=<your database url>`. This will ensure the if statement will return true and execute the first block